# I tried to have 2 buttons, one changing the bgcolor of body to white, the other to black (i want a light mode and dark mdeo for my website)

Tags: javascript, html

Right now it does not change the color of the background

This is my html code:

```
<button onclick="light_mode()">Light mode</button>
<button onclick="dark_mode()">Dark mode</button>
```

this is my javascript:

```
function dark_mode() {
        document.getElementById('body').x.style.background = "color:black";
    }
    function light_mode() {
        document.getElementById('body').x.style.background = "color:white";
    }
```

I gave the body an id "body" so the js would work. Right now it does not work though. Im a beginner at javascript so pls simple explanation. Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason for using `.x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing the changing of the colours is a bit off. Here's a corrected version of your JavaScript:

```
function dark_mode() {
    document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function light_mode() {
    document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

And, your HTML should look something like this:

```
<body id="body">
    <!-- Your content goes here -->

    <button onclick="light_mode()">Light mode</button>
    <button onclick="dark_mode()">Dark mode</button>

    <!-- More content if you have -->
</body>
```

Be sure to let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: Thank you! But when I use this, It changes the color of everything inside of "body" to black except for a couple of input fields i have. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: actually never mind I just forgot to set a color for my divs

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the background color of the inputs, but if everything is black you wont see the input

```css
input{
background-color:black;
}

body{
background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<body>

<input>

</body>
```